# Format=RAW parameter for "Users.threads: get" request

Tags: gmail-api

I'd like to get raw messages for a particilar thread via "Users.threads: get" request. Is it possible to use format=raw parameter in this request somehow? I know it is possible for message request but I really need to do that for this one.

Comment: Why do you want to use the Users.thread get instead of Users.messages? If you used messages instead of thread you could achieve your goal easily, if you don't mind this as a solution I'll it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to specify the format (raw or minimal) when requesting a thread, unfortunately this is not currently possible. The format can only be set for a message request. Requesting a thread in raw format however would not be a good idea since a thread could contain many large messages.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the format, but for some reason google doesn't allow the `raw` format when getting threads.
See [the docs here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/get#Format)